Can terraform read secrets from an infisical?
I have found some documentation that allows me to create secrets and uplaod them to infisical as seen here : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Infisical/infisical/latest/docs/resources/secret but I cannot find anything about reading secrets fron infisical.
The idea would be to have the sensitive data stored in the infisical and have terraform conect to it through client id / client secret to retrieve values such as passwords to then use them ( the infisical is also used for many other programs that I use so it is conviniant to have everything in the same place )

Your link is to the "resource" section of the provider documentation. In Terraform, "resources" are the things you're asking TF to build.
Here's a link to the "data sources" section of the provider documentation. In Terraform, "data sources" are how you can query an external entity, like a secrets provider, so you can use those values in your TF.
